# How to import data from a particular table from a large postgres file?

Tags: postgresql

I want to import data just for particular tables in Postgres. How can I do that?

I've tried the following command. Didnt worked though.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -a -d -t data_pptlconfig db_name  > db_file
```

Comment: Import to postgres or export from postgres ?

Comment: pg_dump is intended for export (backups). Also, the `> db_file` can only write to the db_file, it cannot read from it.

Comment: Assuming you mean "a dump" when you say a "postgres file" ... what format is the dump? If it's an SQL format dump, you'd have to extract the part you want with a text editor. If it's a custom-format dump, you can use `pg_restore` with the `-t` flag. Use `file the-dump-file` to find out which it is if you do not know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "a dump" when you say a "postgres file":

If it's an SQL format dump, you'd have to extract the part you want with a text editor and run just that part. The dump is essentially an SQL "program" to re-create the database, so there's really no other way to selectively restore bits of it.

If it's a custom-format dump, you can use `pg_restore` with the `-t` flag.

Use `file the-dump-file` to find out which it is if you do not know. Or look at the file with a text editor - if the first five bytes are PGDMP it's a PostgreSQL custom format dump; otherwise it'll be an SQL format dump.